# Counteracting effect at the end of hover

Tags: css

I have read a tutorial on how to perform the following effect, it does it correctly, but when I take the mouse out of it what it doesn't do is to do the same in reverse, and the tutorial doesn't explain it.

What am I doing wrong?

```
.contenedor-efecto:hover img {
    transition: 1.5s;
    -webkit-transform:scale(1.3);
    transform:scale(1.3);
}

.contenedor-efecto {
    overflow: hidden;
    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `transition: 1.5s;` needs to be applied at a higher level.

At the moment, when you stop hovering, the transition style is no longer applied, so the change is immediate. If you apply it to the un-hovered selector, it will apply in both directions:

```css
.contenedor-efecto img {
  /* This is now applied here, outside of the hover selector */
  transition: 1.5s;
}

.contenedor-efecto:hover img {
  /* The transition style has been removed from here */
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
  transform: scale(1.3);
}

.contenedor-efecto {
  overflow: hidden;
}

/* This is not part of the solution, but it makes the example work well */
.contenedor-efecto {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="contenedor-efecto">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/200" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To run transitions in both direction needs two classes: the original-(not hover)-class and the hover-class. The property which changes has to be described in both classes with the different states. Then the element can change between the states.

To your example it means:

```
// add class to describe original state for scale
// note transition time here
.contenedor-efecto img {
    transform: scale(1);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transition: all 1.5s;
}
    
.contenedor-efecto:hover img {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
    transform: scale(1.3);
    /* optional: transition: all 1.5s; */
}
```